# SQL Adding Within Statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I would like to return a bunch of columns and add one of them.

**Table**: 
OrderID 
OrderNum 
Amount

I'd like to return the OrderID, Amount and a sum of the amount per orderID. Something like so (OrderID - OrderNum - Amount - Total):

- 1 - O1 - $4 - $10
- 1 - O1 - $3 - $10
- 1 - O1 - $3 - $10
- 2 - O2 - $4 - $8
- 2 - O2 - $3 - $8
- 2 - O2 - $1 - $8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you can use window functions:

```
SELECT 
    OrderID,
    OrderNum,
    Amount ,
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID) as Total
FROM OrderLine
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.orderid, t1.amount, t2.sum_amount
from your_table t1
join 
( 
  select orderid, sum(amount) as sum_amount
  from your_table
  group by orderid
) t2 on t1.orderid = t2.orderid
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did the t2 come from? Either I'm having morning blindness or you pulled an alias out of thin air

Comment: Start of last line: `t2 on t1.orderid = t2.orderid`. `t2` is the alias for the subquery

Comment: So t2 is an alias for those three lines then?

Comment: For the resulting temp table of those 3 lines